# Почему тут не ставятся запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой (?) и ещё кой-какие привлекательные узелки (?) и коробочки.

Почему тут не ставятся запятые ?

Answer (score 3):

**Из-под сена виднелись: (1) самовар, (2)кадка с мороженной формой и ещё кой-какие привлекательные (3)узелки  и (4)коробочки.**

Здесь два союза И, но они не являются повторяющимися, схема соединения 1, 2 и (3 и 4). Между однородными членами 3 и 4 более тесная связь.

Правило:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

8. Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом и, образуют тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом и с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится: Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и быстро сбегала и сохла по канавам (Л. Т.)

Comment: Согласна, вот только в  слове  мороженой - одно  Н.

Comment: Это вроде бы из Л.Н. Толстого, везде пишут НН. Не очень ясно, что такое "мороженная форма", может быть, форма для изготовления мороженого.  http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/rules/157

Comment: А я читала-читала, не поняла вообще, о чём речь. Не догадалась найти текст. Да, здесь, вероятно, форма для мороженого, значит, -НН-